# Time out while i fetch data from SQL in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I hava a database which only have 2 table `Object` , `User` ,

Obviously user table has information about all user and the object table have millions of records

**ObjectTable**

1. Id (int)
2. Text1 (nvarchar(max))
3. Text2 (nvarchar(max))

I am trying to make a translator , first of all i put all data in database like following

1 : Good , Well
2 : Bad , NotWell
3 : Man , Husband Of Women

if suppose i havae 2 text boxes in my site user enter following text

`Good Bad Man`

then i will split that string on space and then i will have an array of string now i will took first element of array and go to server to find that wheather there is any match of `Good` in my database if i found match then i will replace that value with that `Text2` like we have `Well` for `Good`  which took too much time to translate and sometime it gives `Request Timed Out` . So , what is the best way to deal with it

Comment: The exception raised with the call stack would help us help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not provide a lot of information to help you about your timeout problem.

Only things I can tell you are :

- first of all, check that there are indexes on your Text1 and Text2 columns. If not, add it
- look at your sql query. It should be `SELECT * FROM OBJECT WHERE TEXT1='Good'` (maybe add a top 100 to avoid returning to many things with LIKE ).
  For the index to run smoothly, there should be no function called on column TEXT1 (like uppercase or trim). If you use a like, it should be TEXT1 LIKE 'good%' (% at the end)
- if you use a like, beware of not returning your whole table on a empty entry, % or _ entry ( LIKE '%', LIKE '%%', LIKE '_%' can be bad things)
- why use nvarchar(max) if you are just storing words ?
- don't forget to sanitize your entries to avoid sql injection